# how to find the version of hyperledger fabric from command line

Tags: hyperledger, blockchain

How to find the version of hyperledger fabric installed locally,  from command line to understand if its version is 1.0 or 1.1 to avoid conflicts when trying to download and run samples?

Answer (score 3):

execute the following command

```
docker exec cli peer version
```

Comment: worked thanks. Need to check on VM instead in containers.

Answer (score 2):

Print current version of the fabric peer server.

Usage:
  peer version [flags]

Flags:
  -h, --help   help for version

Else from package.json file of a project you can check and do a npm install after cloning a project repository.

Answer (score 0):

There's also the possibility of checking docker images that are currently running using `docker ps`. For example, if you are running fabric 1.1 you will see something like: `hyperledger/fabric-peer:1.1.0`, `hyperledger/fabric-orderer:1.1.0` and `hyperledger/fabric-ca:1.1.0` in the IMAGE column.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ docker images
```

should work if your running linux

Answer (score 0):

You can run `peer version` or `orderer version`

OUTPUT

```
vagrant@vagrant:/vagrant$ peer version
peer:
 **Version: 2.1.0**
 Commit SHA: 1bdf97537
 Go version: go1.14.1
 OS/Arch: linux/amd64
 Chaincode:
  Base Docker Label: org.hyperledger.fabric
  Docker Namespace: hyperledger
```